# Introductory multivariate statistics reference for beginners

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, references

I am from computer science department doing research in data mining and image mining. I remember the last course about stat was introductory to statistics and probability in general. Now I have this course in master degree Multivariate statistical analysis and it's only for 1 month and it's very difficult to understand a lot of concepts. I need an easy to follow book about the subject of Multivariate statistical analysis for beginner!

Comment: What are the topics of your course? Does the course instructor recommend a book?

Comment: The course instructor book is in Chinese! So i need English easy to follow book. I visited the library and i saw Richard Johnson Applied on multivariate analysis and it was very hard, and i saw Anderson introduction to Multivariate statistics and i could not understand the first page!

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information. Do you need a conceptual or a more mathematical introduction? What should be covered in the book? Based on my psychological background I'd probably recommend either the book from [Tabachnik & Fidell](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Using-Multivariate-Statistics-6E/0205849571.page) or [Hair et al.](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Multivariate-Data-Analysis/9780138132637.page). Especially the last one is well written and easily understandable. However, they do not cover anything about data mining.

Comment: Have you searched for `[references] machine learning` on this site? There are already multiple answers for your question.

Comment: I would like the book to be related to data mining and machine learning in general, but looks like those books are advance on me. With that being said i will be happy to have introductory book at least to understand something! i don't understand what is a conceptual or a more mathematical introduction? I am programmer so science words are hard for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your question, your program sounds similar to the many accelerated MS degrees with 6-8 week courses on each subject. I would recommend to go for statistics or econometrics texts for executive MBAs to survive. The EMBA level texts are easy to follow and do not expect strong math background. e.g. [Wharton's EMBA](http://executivemba.wharton.upenn.edu/academics/curriculum-overview/) program has [Stat 613](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/11827788/waiver-information-guide-whartons-spike-university-of-/63) as core course, and it uses [Stine and Foster's text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321836510).

It's good to set the expectations right though. It's impossible to learn statistics without at least calculus and linear algebra, so if your definition of "easy" is without these two skills, then you're not going to learn anything useful in one month, but it's Ok. It's just the nature of these degrees, you only need to get an exposure to the field, i.e. very similar to EMBA objectives.

For programmers I'd recommend fun books such as [R by Example](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461413646) in Springer's [Use R!](http://www.springer.com/series/6991) series. I read it while learning R already knowing statistics, but think that it can be used to learn both R and statistics. R is rather interesting language for programmers, it's based loosely on functional programming (FP) paradigm. That's why if your programmer friend is a hardcore programmer, he must know stuff like Haskell or Scala, and will feel comfortable picking a new FP language, especially because FP is fashionable again these days.

Another title in the same series is [An Introduction to Applied Multivariate Analysis with R](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-1-4419-9649-7). If your friend is in good school, he will probably have SpringerLink access through his library, i.e. free PDF download of a book.

Comment: "It's impossible to learn statistics without at least calculus and linear algebra" Across many disciplines (no names!) the **majority** of practitioners of statistics have little or no background in those subjects, or at least that they can recall. Naturally it limits their understanding of the foundations, but equally much publishable work using statistics comes from such researchers. But I agree that "easy to follow" is difficult to comment on. I've not met anyone who wanted a book difficult to follow.

Comment: Okay thanks Nick, i mean by easy to follow not for advance but for beginner (programmer not mathematician student).

Comment: Let me see your response Aksakal and i will review it. Yeas actually i am for 2 years not rush master, but the course is for one month !!

Comment: @MohammadAhmed, you don't need to be math student to know calculus or linear algebra, it's a requirement in many quant majors, such as physics or engineering. Programmers are a different kind, they're sort of engineers, yet their math background is more like liberal arts. That's why you better look for texts not for engineers, but for "business" or liberal arts folks.

Comment: Yeah i need it for computer science student whose his background is less mathematical than math students. Do you you have book recommendation?

Comment: @Aksakal In an international and cross-disciplinary forum we can expect all kinds of backgrounds and personal trajectories. Programmers or business people who started as mathematicians or physicists won't fit the picture you sketch. I expect that you will agree, but careless wording can cause puzzlement or even (unintended!) offence here.

Comment: @MohammadAhmed, for a programmer it's more fun to read a book with a lot of coding examples, e.g. this one http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-1-4419-9649-7 or many others in the same Use R! series. I think that too much code is often distracting, but this Springer series usually have a good balance of code and background

Comment: @Aksakal what about Richard Johnso Applied multivariate statistics book i think it's good as it has some introduction. The Elements of Statistical Learning Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction. i think they are good. what do you think ?

Comment: @MohammadAhmed, I haven't read these. I know that the latter is mentioned a lot, and the reason is Coursera. JHU's data science courses refer to it.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but i saw the first chapter on amazon, content and some pages, i think it's much easier that introduction to multivariate statistics. i mean Richard Johanson book. Can you check Johanson in Amazon for content and first chapters then give me you opinion? it's very important. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think i will borrow a book from library for Statistics For Dummies and richard johanson and read them at the same time !! becuase i find both good and easy to understand ? Do you agree with me Aksakal?

Comment: @MohammadAhmed, "for Dummies", really?

Comment: If you need to read introductory statistics texts, you aren't ready for a multivariate course.

Comment: @Aksakal okay i will take An Introduction to Applied Multivariate Analysis with R and Statistics for Business: Decision Making and Analysis (2nd Edition) for easy reading thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Multivariate statistics is very broad, but given your background I'd recommend "Introduction to Statistical Learning" http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ It's a really nice intro book to modern multivariate techniques that are popular in data mining and machine learning. You can get the PDF for free.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i need one which is easy to follow not advanced or hardcore. 
I visited the library and i saw Richard Johnson Applied on multivariate analysis and it was very hard, and i saw Anderson introduction to Multivariate statistics and i could not understand the first page!!
So as you see i am fresh to statistics and this class is a must for me to do.

Comment: The first one aims at being a gentle introduction. It won't get much easier than that.

Comment: You mean Richard Johnson Applied on multivariate analysis? So what i some concept are hard! Do you have prerequisite book for it?

Comment: No, I mean the book in my answer!